# Case insensitive links for microsite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a microsite named www.domain.com/site1
 Which works properly as the directory is named as site1 in small alphabet. I want the same microsite when the url is www.domain.com/SITE1 and also the link in the browser should not change.

Please help with htaccess solution or any other alternative will do.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to convert all your file names to a lowercase. And then you can use `RewriteMap` to make URLs case-insensitive.

This `RewriteMap` should be added into `<VirtualHost>` section.

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

`RewriteRule` may be added into `.htaccess` file.
This rule will rewrite all URLs containig uppercase letters to lowercase files.

```
RewriteRule [A-Z] ${lc:%{REQUEST_URI}} [L]
```